# Command panics with process cannot access the file already being used

Tags: rust, process, command, std

I'm trying to spawn a CLI in my Rust code via `Comand::new`. CLI file is extracting from binary files to exe file and then run with `Command::new`. But It gives `'ERROR: Os { code: 32, kind: Other, message: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." }'` error.

```
let taskmgr_pid = get_pid_by_name("Taskmgr.exe");
let process_hide = asset::Asset::get("cli.exe").unwrap();

let file_path = "C:\\filepathhere\\cli.exe";

let mut file = File::create(file_path.to_string()).expect("Couldn't create file");
file.write_all(&process_hide);

let res = Command::new(file_path)
    .arg(taskmgr_pid.to_string())
    .output()
    .expect("ERROR");

println!("PID: {}", taskmgr_pid);
println!("{:?}", res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't close `file` prior to executing the command. The easiest way to resolve the issue, is to simply [`drop(file);`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) prior to [`Command::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.new).

```rust
let mut file = File::create(file_path).expect("unable to create file");
file.write_all(&process_hide).expect("unable to write");

drop(file);

let res = Command::new(file_path)
    .arg(taskmgr_pid.to_string())
    .output()
    .expect("ERROR");
```